# logstash OutOfMemory error when importing 20 million rows from postgres to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, import, out-of-memory, logstash

I have 20million rows sql dump file from postgresql . I want to move it to elasticsearch so I use logstash and i use this statement : `statement => "select * from students"`. but I always get outOfMemory error . I have 16g ram and I change the logstash and elasticsearch XMx to 12g but this error have occured yet . I think it is because of select statement. It make a huge load on memory . what Should i do ? thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to configure these paramters

- jdbc_fetch_size - to specify the fetch size.
  Here is the link to it->https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_dealing_with_large_result_sets

Moreover use following parameters for paging results from sql queries

- jdbc_page_size
- jdbc_paging_enabled

This will internally use sql limit property.

Comment: thank you for your help . I am testing again with jdbc_fetch_size = 300 .

Comment: but i have the same error after set fetch size to 300 2018-02-18T12:39:31,804][WARN ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>#<Sequel::DatabaseError: Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space>}

Comment: You must be aware of sql limit query using sort parameter which queries retrieves results from sql of that size only.
Read of how to use i in elasticsearch over this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-jdbc_page_size.
I have mentioned these parameters above

Answer (score 1):

These threads may help : [enter link description here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/issues/9)  and [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156145/heap-space-error-while-executing-logstash-with-a-large-dictionary-translate-fil/54404652#54404652)

To summarize, as mentioned by Gaurav above, when this kind of issue occurred, you have to add below params in jdc section of your config file

```
jdbc {
   jdbc_paging_enabled => true,
   jdbc_page_size => 200000
}
```